# Running a series of daily PHP scripts in multiple processes

Tags: php, multithreading, cron, backup, supervisord

Hoping you can help! I am currently building and testing a PHP script that ports data from one web system to another (think data backup) that needs to run daily for an indefinite number of users. The script is fairly intensive, depending on the amount of data that needs to be pulled (the longest execution time I have seen thus far has been about 30 minutes).

Given that, I obviously don't want to run them one after the other, as the whole job won't complete in a timely fashion. So ideally, I would like to have some way to schedule the job so that it can run up to ten (which I can expand as server capacity increases) backups simultaneously. When one script completes, it picks up the next at the top of the pile (a single pile rather than 10) an executes it, and so on. Now, it is possible (and at this stage probable) that some of the instances are going to fail with a fatal error and die. That is fine, as I am handling that with a custom error handler, but obviously I don't want the failure of one instance to have any bearing on the others.

Having read some of the other questions on here, I have seen PHP forking and Supervisord discussed, but to be honest, casting my mind back 7 years to my process scheduling paper has defeated me! It would be really great to get some advise of how to implement something like this, if it is at all possible? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) to execute multiple commands asynchronously. If the backup process is itself a PHP script, it can be run using the php binary (e.g. php mybackupscript.php)

Comment: Ok, so how can I use this to set a limit on the number of processes running at a time? Presumably this has some kind of callback that happens that can then trigger the next to fire?

Comment: Actually, I think the following may work for that - if every instance called does the follow?

do {
 $resourse = $database->query( /* Some query to decide the next backup that needs to be run */ );
 if ( ! mysqli_num_rows( $resourse ) ) break;
 $back_result = $resourse->fetch_object();
 $backup_id_to_run = $back_result->backup_id;
 $database->query( /* Update the backup record to say that it's been started so the other processes don't try to run it */ );
    @include( '/path/to/backup/script.php' );
} while ( true );

I assume PHP 5.3's garbage collection could handle it? Any other problems?